# Firebase Firestore How to Know if the UserId Already Exists in an Array so I can Remove It

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I am building a Twitter like functionality for the app and I want to be able to update the likes for a tweet.

Here is my basic setup:

[image]

As you can see I have likes collection. Each like document id is a Tweet ID and that contains the tweet document id and the userIds array. When a user like a tweet, userId is added to the userIds array. The problem is that now I have to unlike a tweet so I have to remove the id from the userIds array.

```
 let _ =  try await db.collection("likes")
                .document(like.tweetDocumentId)
                .setData([
                    "tweetDocumentId": like.tweetDocumentId,
                    "userIds": [like.userId]
                ])
```

Is this the correct approach or should I make users a collection inside the likes. But in that cases what will the leaf node looks like.

`likes/TweetID/users/UserId -> The leaf can contain the tweetDocumentId and userId`. That can make deleting easier but will it be good for performance to create a users collection for each like.

Answer (score 0):

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION**

```
do {
            
            // check if the user has already likes if so then remove userId from the collection
            let docRef = db.collection("likes")
                .document(like.tweetDocumentId)
                .collection("users")
                .document(like.userId)
            
            let doc = try await docRef.getDocument()
            if doc.exists {
                // delete it
                try await doc.reference.delete()
            } else {
                try await db.collection("likes")
                    .document(like.tweetDocumentId)
                    .collection("users")
                    .document(like.userId)
                    .setData([
                        "tweetDocumentId": like.tweetDocumentId,
                        "userId": like.userId
                    ])
            }
            
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
```

Comment: Ok but now you're treating the Answer field as a question, it seems. I'm sorry I tried to straighten this out.